# How to get an URL from a server with parameter with Angular 6

Tags: angular, rest, web-services, angular6

i'am trying to get an URL from java backend in my angular's application,i have to pass the number of the folder inside the URL in order to get a list from that folder, what's the appropriate fomat that i should write ? how to personalize it in order to accept any number of folder , for this example 255

this's the URL

```
enter code here

public DD_LIST = '/app/api/demandes/225/listesdemanedes';
```

and the service is :

```
enter code here   getlistes(): Observable<any> {
const api = {method : 'GET', url : this.DD_LIST };
return  this.http.request(api, null).pipe(
  map(response => ({
      content: response
  }))
);
```

}

Comment: Not able to understand your question.. Can you explain it in bit more detail?

Comment: for example i have an URL like this: 
http://localhost:8080/app/api/demandes/26288/listesdemanedes
how to personalize the URL in ANGULAR

Comment: do you want to pass 26288 into your `DD_LIST `?

Comment: in fact i have many folders with different numbers 
i want to customize the URL so he can accept any number of folder in the list of my folders

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript string interpolation to form the URL as like below,

```
let folderNumber = 225;
public DD_LIST = `/app/api/demandes/${folderNumber}/listesdemanedes`;
```